# como hacer para que cuando pase el cursor por un boton una imagen se oscuresca?

Tags: css, css3, scss, selectores-css, css-transform

```
.visitanos__contenido-boton {
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 68%;
  left: 43%;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 15%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

cómo hago para vincular mi botón con la iamgen para cuando pase el cursor sobre el botón ésta se oscuresca sin usar javascript

```
.visitanos__contenido-image {
  background: #2a2c2f;
  width: 1184px;
  height: 740px;
  margin-top: 15%;
  opacity:0.7;
}
```

aquí está mi css, cómo se vicula mi botón con la imagen para que ésta se oscuresca?

Comment: Cuando pasas por encima de algo, se lanza el evento hover en css, por lo que debes usarlo así: .visitanos__contenido-image:hover { lo que sea }

Comment: Como es la estructura HTML donde estan? Pega eso por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se puede vincular el :hover de la primera clase con la clase de la imagen usando el "+", a fin de conseguir lo que dices (si te he entendido bien). Te pongo unos códigos de ejemplo. He utilizado tus snippets pero los he simplificado un poco para que se pueda reproducir rápidamente y sin problemas.

Espero que te ayude:

```css
.visitanos__contenido-boton {
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 15%;
  text-align: center;
}

.visitanos__contenido-image {
  background: #2a2c2f;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity:0.7;
}

.visitanos__contenido-boton:hover + .visitanos__contenido-image{
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<button class="visitanos__contenido-boton">Visit us</button>
<div class="visitanos__contenido-image"></div>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, te agradesco mucho esa fue la solución

Comment: Genial. Un placer!